# Checking whether the variable is a number in VTL

Tags: velocity

Walked through the docs of Velocity Template Language, How could one check that whether a variable is of type int or string and how to compare with regular expressions in VTL, please guide me

Comment: What have you done so far and what is your velocity version ?

Comment: Have an open-source java application installed on my system, that allows to configure the input parameters in Dashboard, thats where I came across Velocity template, could find its docs, but was not able to get the one I wanted

Comment: You can use normal Java regular expression in velocity also

Answer (score 2):

Velocity holds objects in context. You can check your variable as a String.

In velocity you can use regular expression as Java using $ for getting variable in context.

```
 $variableName.matches("^-?\\d+$");
```

Also you can check if it's an Integer by comparing `"java.lang.Integer"` to `${variableName.class.name}`

Comment: You can check if it's an Integer by comparing "java.lang.Integer" to ${variableName.class.name}

Comment: Give an example please

Comment: #if( $variableName.class.name == "java.lang.Integer" )